# Name for the set of unique $\{a, f(a), f(f(a)), ... \}$?

Tags: terminology

Is there a name for the unique values produced by recursive function calls? Something like

$f(x) =$ (recursive applications of) $(x \cdot 2) \mod 6$
$f(1) = \{1, 2, 4\}$

Thank you.

Comment: Sometimes "orbit", particularly if the function is invertible.

Comment: But careful, the word orbit means a lot of things and must be used properly, depending on the context.

Comment: @Ethan: How can it be orbit if it doesn't include $f^{-1}(a)$ and its iterates?

Comment: "Closure" is a commonly used, and very appropriate, term for this set. It is the smallest set closed under $f$ such that $a$ is in that set.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Yours is the clearest answer to me. Would you mind posting it as an answer so I can select it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One appropriate term would be "The closure of $\{a\}$ under $f$", since $\{f^n(a)\mid n\in\Bbb N\}=\{a,f(a),f(f(a)),\dots\}$ is in fact the smallest set containing $a$ which is closed under $f$.

Of course, $\{a\}$ can be replaced by any subset of the domain of $f$.

Answer (score 2):

These are called fixed point iterates, and the process is called fixed point iteration.

In dynamical systems, the term *orbit* is used as well, as Ethan Bolker indicated in his comment.